# Как выключить компьютер с помощью rust?

Tags: rust

Может ли rust выключить компьютер, как это было был на python?
Что-то в подобии `os.system("shutdown /p")`на пайтон или `WinExec("shutdown -s -t 0", SW_HIDE` на C++

Comment: Точно так же: вбить в гyгл `rust call process` и открыть [первую же ссылку](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html) в результатах поиска

Comment: @andreymal спасибо не знал как сформулировать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обратите внимание на [std::process::Command](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html)

```rust
use std::process::Command;

let output = if cfg!(target_os = "windows") {
    Command::new("cmd")
            .args(["/C", "echo hello"])
            .output()
            .expect("failed to execute process")
} else {
    Command::new("sh")
            .arg("-c")
            .arg("echo hello")
            .output()
            .expect("failed to execute process")
};

let hello = output.stdout;
```